# is server name required for only backend for nginx setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I am trying to setup nginx on my ubuntu machine. I went through the tutorial about [how to setup nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04). In that tutorial there is code as shown below:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here, as I have my backend on aws. So what should I put in the field **server_name**?

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), but for a single `server` block configuration, the `server_name` is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your server_name set to a public IP if you don't have a name. Your request needs to reach the server. Without a name, you will not be able to have two different server blocks on the same port.